# Airflow Helm - deployed extraContainer with GCS sync through cron runs but nothing happens

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying airflow helm using argoCD and I due to some company policies, usual solutions for syncing the git repo containing all the information of the application, such as gitSync or a shared Volume on kubernetes where we can push through a gitAction, are out of question.  A work-around I could think about was to create a sideContainer that would run a cronjob pulling data from a GCS bucket (that would be populated via a gitAction) every n minutes.

I have installed GCP tool kit (**gsutil** for moving data and **gcloud** for auth) into my docker image and created a very simple cronjob that should run every minute under the user **airflow**

`* * * * * gsutil -m cp -r gs://mybucket/airflow_k8/dagsv2/* /opt/airflow/gcs/dagsv2`

When I build & run the image locally with the following ENTRYPOINT I obtain a functional image that regularly triggers the cronjob above & pulls data from GCS to my destination folder

`["bash", "-c", "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/opt/airflow/creds/gcp_dataeng_secret.json && cron -f"]`

The next step was to deploy it into the workers & scheduler for sync purposes, then I created the following piece of code

```
helm: |
...
# giving my GCP secret gcp_dataeng_secret.json to all components in airflow.
volumes:
 - name: gcp-secret-path
   secret:
      secretName: airflow-gcp-dataeng-secret
... 
workers / scheduler :     #same piece of code for both, since it is the same sideContainer
              ...
              extraVolumes:
                - name: dags-folder
                  emptyDir: {}
 # maybe mounting the volume here is not even needed since I mounted it already in the extraContainer, but tried to be safe than sorry
              extraVolumeMounts:
                - name: dags-folder
                  mountPath: /opt/airflow/gcs/dagsv2
              extraContainers:
                - name: cron-job
                  image: my-gcs-sync-customImage:latest# giving airflow user to securityContext since the job is defined under airflow
                  securityContext:
                    runAsUser: 50000
                  volumeMounts:
                    - name: gcp-secret-path
                      mountPath: /opt/airflow/creds
                      readOnly: true
                    - name: dags-folder
                      mountPath: /opt/airflow/gcs/dagsv2
                      readOnly: false
# the --key-file is mounted with gcp-secret-path and I launch my cron with cron -f
                  command: ["bash", "-c", "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/opt/airflow/creds/gcp_dataeng_secret.json && cron -f"]
...
config:
 core:
   dags_folder: /opt/airflow/gcs/dagsv2
```

When I deploy this piece of code above, I can see that the cron-job side Container is created successfully and no error message is displayed, which makes me think that it is working fine, but then no DAGs appear in the UI ! I have played a lot with the configurations but nothing seemed to work, although I feel that I am missing something very basic since I am a beginner at kubernetes. I cant access the kubectl neither due to the company policy

**Some Considerations**

- when I did not pass the **gcp-secret-path** inside the extraContainers I got a message that the command could not find the creds, which means that the job is at least being triggered.
- there is a similar idea of this implementation but with s3 described here https://swalloow.github.io/airflow-sidecar/ (although it is in Korean)
- I have tried giving the *securityContext: runAsUser: 0* or even removing the field but it did not change anything
- the secret is valid because I am using it (also mounted at /opt/airflow/creds/gcp_dataeng_secret.json) to write the logs, plus it has writing & reading permissions